# Celestial mechanics simulation software? The 'N-Body Problem'

Tags: software, simulation, computational-physics, open-source

What software or sites might simulate an **N-body gravitational problem**? Application is related to [Klemperer Rosette](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klemperer_rosette) or [Iridium Satellites](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iridium_satellite_constellation).  Bias for C, C++, PHP, or Java. Nice visuals a big plus.

Similar questions are here in Computation Science for [binary stars](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/10494/7556), [satellites](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/7448/7556) and [comets](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/7584/7556) but I need to simulate several  planet-size celestial bodies over long timescales (1K - 1M years) to determine stability. Asked questions related to my application on [Space Exploration](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/3872/213) and [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/101354/20241) but haven't gotten much interest or answers. Turning here to consider researching myself.

Possibilities so far:

- [ORSA](http://sourceforge.net/projects/orsa/files/) sounds promising but is 10 years old, has six errors on install, and crashes.  I have it showing a cute little Earth going around a cute little Sun at about 20 samples per second.  It will export thousands of PNGs but not an AVI.
- [ODTBX](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/odtbx/wiki/WikiStart) seems more for artificial satellites around Earth and may require MATLAB.
- [Celestia](http://sourceforge.net/projects/celestia/) seems more for visual rendering than long-term simulation.
- [GMAT](http://gmatcentral.org/display/GW/GMAT+Wiki+Home) seems more for interplanetary spacecraft of a negligible mass.

Comment: mentioning that you value this less than $500 could actually discourage the faceless pool of underexploited crowd source talent from writing this for you for free

Comment: Are you looking for a generic N-Body simulator or do you require real-time visualisation?

Comment: Simulation without visualization would still be useful @aragilar.

Answer (score 1):

Some n-body simulators I aware of are:
1. Gadget: http://www.mpa-garching.mpg.de/gadget/
2. nbody6: http://www.ast.cam.ac.uk/~sverre/web/pages/nbody.htm
3. swift: http://www.boulder.swri.edu/~hal/swift.html (but this may be hard to install)